# No entiendo cómo funciona el método .hasNext() de la clase Scanner

Tags: java

Buenas tardes a todos.

Estoy realizando el siguiente ejercicio de programación competitiva : https://www.aceptaelreto.com/problem/statement.php?id=441
. Por si alguien no quiere leer, el enunciado dice básicamente que dado un número formateado con "." para separar los millares, devuelva con el mismo formato el número sumado uno. Ejemplo:

```
Entrada:
1
9
1.345
1.234.567

Salida:
2
10
1.346
1.234.568
```

Del cual tengo el siguiente código:

```
package com.caiomed03.aceptaelreto;


import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class p441 {


    public static String replace(String a) {
        String aux = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (a.charAt(i) == '.') {
                aux += "";
                continue;
            }
            aux += a.charAt(i);
        }
        return aux;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numero;
        DecimalFormat formatea = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            numero = sc.next();

            numero = replace(numero);

            int n = Integer.parseInt(numero) + 1;

            System.out.println(formatea.format(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Resulta que el ejercicio ya lo tengo solucionado y me da las salidas correspondientes pero resulta que la entrada se da línea por la línea, sin indicar cuantas líneas se van a poner, finalizando, entiendo, cuando ya no haya más entrada.
Investigando por Internet encontré que la forma de realizar esto es con el método .hasNext() de la clase Scanner pero resulta que, al copiar y pegar toda la entrada y recibir la salida correspondiente, no se finaliza el programa y se queda colgando y al tratar de mandarlo al juez me da un error de Run-Time, es decir, que se queda colgado y no finaliza. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que finalice? ¿Alguien me puede explicar como funciona bien este método?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error exacto?

Comment: En mi IDE (Netbeans), no se muestra ningún error, simplemente el programa no finaliza, se queda, por así decirlo, como en un bucle infinito. En el juez, el error indicado es Run-time error que se puede encontrar su descripció según la página se encuentra aquí: https://www.aceptaelreto.com/doc/verdicts.php#RTE

Comment: Creo que no has entendido el enunciado: 1. Tu programa no funciona para números de 200 caracteres porque  supera el límite de `int`. 2. Tu programa ha de aceptar una única entrada (un número), Los casos de prueba se introducirán uno a uno, en distintas llamadas. 3. Estás usando comas en lugar de puntos para separar los miles

Comment: Sobre el límite de int totalmente cierto no me había fijado y ya lo he corregido convirtiéndolo a long. Sobre las llamadas, se tiene que hacer un copia y pega de la entrada de ejemplo y tiene que salir exactamente igual la salida para (a veces) pensar que está bien. Sobre las comas, es un tema del DecimalFormat, funciona correctamente tal y como está, lo he probado bastante y en todo momento me muestra el número con "." como separador.

Comment: No obstante, no sé si conoces la plataforma de Acepta el Reto pero estoy seguro en gran medida que el problema es que el programa no finaliza pero puede ser perfectamente que el problema sea algo de lo que me comentas.

Comment: long tampoco te servirá, tienes que aceptar números de hasta 1000 caracteres (asumiendo un punto cada 3 dígitos, son unos 750 dígitos)

Comment: Acabo de ver una resolución en C usando int que asumo que tiene los mismos límites que en Java que es correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Empezando por el principio, si te fijas en la página, verás que te dan un tiempo de "1 seg" para realizar la operación, por si había alguna duda, esto descarta por completo el uso de **Scanner**, se tiene que leer un archivo de texto (supongo que esa parte del programa la ponen ellos).

A ti te llega una cadena con el siguiente formato:

```
1
9
123.123
999
```

solo que la longitud de los números, puede ser de mil dígitos, ahora bien, para tratar con un número de mil dígitos, tienes que prescindir de... los números, tienes que tratarlo como una cadena.

```
String sumarUno( String numeros ) {

      // separamos el texto por lineas
   String num[] = numeros.split( "\n" ); 
   String salida = "";
   for( int i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ) {
      String aux = "";

      // creamos un array de caracteres
      String valores[] = num[ i ].split( "" ); 

      for( int j = valores.length - 1; j > -1; j-- ) {
         String letra = valores[ j ];
         if( letra.equals( "." ) ) {
            continue;
         }
         if( letra.equals( "9" ) ) {

               // si la letra es un "9" cambiamos el valor por "0", si no es la última
               // posición del array, dejamos que se repita el proceso
            valores[ j ] = "0";
            if( j == 0 ) {
                  // si estamos en la última posición del array
                  // si la posición es divisible por 3, agregamos "1.", sino "1"
               if( valores.length % 3 == 0 ) {
                  aux = "1." + cargar( aux, valores );  
               }
               else {
                  aux = "1" + cargar( aux, valores );
               }
               break;
            }
         }
         else {

              // para los valores distintos de "9", cambiamos el valor por el del número más "1" y agregamos en **aux** el contenido del array
            valores[ j ] = "" + ( Integer.parseInt( letra ) +1 );
            aux = cargar( aux, valores );
            break;
         }
      }

         // en cada iteración, agregamos a **salida** el contenido de **aux**, y 
         // si no estamos en la última iteración, agregamos un salto de linea
      salida += aux;
      if( i != num.length -1 ) {
         salida += "\n";
      }

   }
   System.out.println( salida );
   return salida;
}
```

Este método auxiliar carga el la cadena que recibe, el contenido del array.

```
String cargar( String salida, String data[] ) {
   for( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
      salida += data[ i ];
   }
   return salida;
}
```

Esta solución, no pretende ser la mejor, seguro que se puede optimizar, solo espero que sirva de inspiración..

Answer (score 0):

Justo después del ciclo While deberás cerrar el Scanner. En tu caso sería: `sc.close();`
Además el while siempre es verdadero. Por eso el Loop infinito. Una solución sería añadir alguna condición mas que te permita hacerla false y salir del bucle. HasNext se suele utilizar con array que ya tienen un número definitivo. Cuando termina de leer el array la condición es false sale.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            numero = sc.next();

            numero = replace(numero);

            int n = Integer.parseInt(numero) + 1;

            System.out.println(formatea.format(n));
        }
        sc.close();
```

Comment: El programa sigue quedándose colgado, no se soluciona.

Comment: Buenas Caio Medeiros! He editado la respuesta. Espero que te sea útil. Sino me dices a ver si encontramos la solución. Taluego!